# Why does ss.deleteSheet() unhide one hidden sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've written a little script that **automatically deletes all Sheets my user accidentally create**.

Often, when accessing the spreadsheet with their phone, they accidentally click on "+" and create tons of empty sheets, like Sheet101, Sheet102, etc.

My script is very simple: gets all sheets, and **if the name starts with Sheet, just deletes it**.

It works perfectly, but after deleting all the undesired sheets, **the problem** is that it **automatically unhides the first hidden sheet** (some sheets are hidden for practical use, like they contain lists).

*For example, if I have the following hidden sheets:
`oldform`, `list1`, `list2`, ...
After executing the script, the sheet `oldform` will be unhidden, thus appearing to the users.*

Here is two codes I've tried:

**The simple one:**

```
function DELETESHEETS2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if ( sheets[i].getName().indexOf("Sheet") > -1 ) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

**The one I tried to modify to solve my problem:**

```
function DELETESHEETS3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if ( sheets[i].getName().indexOf("Sheet") > -1 ) {
      label = sheets[i].getName();
      toto = ss.getSheetByName(label);
      ss.deleteSheet(toto);
    }
  }
}
```

**The reverse loop**

With this one, the hidden sheet appears at the beginning and not at the end:

```
function DELETESHEETS2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (i = sheets.length -1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    if ( sheets[i].getName().indexOf("Sheet") > -1 ) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

**A partial solution**

This one works, thanks to @OMila. But it does not explain the weird behavior of a simple loop. Maybe I missed something?

```
function DELETESHEETS2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var hdnShts = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if(sheets[i].isSheetHidden()) {
      hdnShts.push(sheets[i].getName()); //saving all the hidden sheet names for later
    }   
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if ( sheets[i].getName().indexOf("Sheet") > -1 ) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

   for(var i = 0; i<hdnShts.length; i++) {
    ss.getSheetByName(hdnShts[i]).hideSheet(); //just to make sure all the hiddens remain hidden
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help if you have any idea!

PS: this problem is easy to reproduce, just create lots of sheets including one with a name other than Sheetxxx

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you step through the `sheets` array in reverse?

Comment: Just tried, but in this case the hidden sheet unhide at the beginning of the loop and now at the end. I can't explain this behavior

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function delSheetsKeepHidden() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = ss.getSheets();
  var hdnShts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < shts.length; i++) {
    if(shts[i].isSheetHidden()) {
      hdnShts.push(shts[i].getName()); //saving all the hidden sheet names for later
    }   
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < shts.length; i++) {
    if(shts[i].getName().slice(0,5).toLowerCase() == "sheet") {
      ss.deleteSheet(shts[i]); //I think this is just deleting the sheet and not the array element in shts so no reason to keep track of deleted sheets like when deleting rows in a spreadsheet
    }
  }
  for(var i = 0; i<hdnShts.length; i++) {
    ss.getSheetByName(hdnShts[i]).hideSheet(); //just to make sure all the hiddens remain hidden
  }
}
```

I've been forcing myself to get away from old school loops.

```
function delSheetsKeepHidden() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var hdnShts=[];
  shts.forEach(function(sht){if(sht.isSheetHidden()){hdnShts.push(sht.getName())}});
  shts.forEach(function(sht){if(sht.getName().slice(0,5).toLowerCase()=="sheet"){ss.deleteSheet(sht);}});//I think this is just deleting the sheet and not the array element in shts so no reason to keep track of deleted sheets like when deleting rows in a spreadsheet
  hdnShts.forEach(function(name){ss.getSheetByName(name).hideSheet();});//just to make sure all the hiddens remain hidden
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing that. Actually, your script is better because you record the list of sheets before you delete them. I would unhide after deleting, and the script would complain I was looping through non existant sheets...

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Your welcome.  Glad to help.  I also added the same function with some of the newer array methods.  I'm trying to force myself into using them more often.

Comment: I'm super noob with Google Scripts/Javascripts but it looks cool, going to look into it